# CheckBox is not drawn with its tick

Tags: android

When I started my application in Android 8.0, I saw any checked CheckBox is drawn without the tick:
[image: a wrong tick]

if I rotate my phone, the Activity is recreated and the checked CheckBox looks correctly:
[image]

I tried to set checked state and invoke invalidate() for CheckBox, but it didn't make any difference. The issue is in both the emulator and the real phone.

[My test project to reproduce the issue](https://github.com/IvanKovalchuk/Android8Error)

Comment: can share layout and code

Comment: The sources are quite big, so here is the [link_to_class](https://github.com/IvanKovalchuk/PhoneRecorderN/blob/master/phoneRecorder/src/main/java/com/kivsw/phonerecorder/ui/settings/SettingsFragment.java) [link_to_layout](https://github.com/IvanKovalchuk/PhoneRecorderN/blob/master/phoneRecorder/src/main/res/layout/setting_fragment.xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I understood it's an android's bug. Here's [the link to the bug report.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111734667)

I can reproduce it in a test project: https://github.com/IvanKovalchuk/Android8Error

The issue appears when a CheckBox is placed in a PageViewer and CheckBox's state is set in onStart(), onResume()

As a workaround I set CheckBox's state in onCreateView() method.

Answer (score 0):

try this trick

```
yourCheckBox.post(()-{
    yourCheckBox.setChecked(true)
})
```